# Take the maximum in absolute value from different columns and filter out NaN Python

Tags: python, pandas, max, nan, absolute-value

This was my try. For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[5,0,1,np.nan], 'b':[np.nan,1,4,3], 'c':[-3,-2,0,0]})
df.dropna(axis=1).max(axis=1,key=abs)
```

Filters out well the `NaN` values but it gets 0 or negative values instead of the highes in absolute value

The result should be one column with

```
5
-2
4
3
```

Comment: when you do `dropna` you losing all columns with `NaN` values and only `c` column is left

Comment: Ok. At any case if i use df.max(axis=1,key=abs)
it does not take the max in absolute value but just the max positive

Answer (score 15):

I solved by

```
maxCol=lambda x: max(x.min(), x.max(), key=abs)
df.apply(maxCol,axis=1)
```

Comment: this solution works, but really slow... is there a faster solution?

Comment: How could I alter this so that it takes the absolute minimum value? I tried to replace max with min so min(x.min(),x.max(),key=abs) but that did not work.

Comment: @AlonGouldman my answer below should be more efficient if you're having performance issues.

Comment: @AndrewHamel replace `max()` with `min()` in my answer below and it should work

Comment: @Brendan I wanted (and also the OP) to keep the negative values. your way converts them into positive

Comment: @AlonGouldman Good clarification! In that case I'd recommend something like `df.idxmax()` to get the indices of the maxima, then use those indices to select the original values in the original df. This approach should still outperform any apply operations.

Answer (score 9):

The most straightforward and efficient way is to convert to absolute values, and then find the max. Pandas supports this with straightforward syntax ([abs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.abs.html) and [max](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html)) and does not require expensive apply operations:

```
df.abs().max()
```

`max()` accepts an `axis` argument, which can be used to specify whether to calculate the max on rows or columns.

Comment: This wouldn't answer the question asked because it removes the negative values.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `np.nanargmax` on the squared data:

```
>>> df.values[range(df.shape[0]),np.nanargmax(df**2,axis=1)]
array([ 5., -2.,  4.,  3.])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df.fillna(0)
l = df.abs().values.argmax(axis=1)
pd.Series([df.values[i][l[i]] for i in range(len(df.values))])

In [532]: pd.Series([df.values[i][l[i]] for i in range(len(df.values))])
Out[532]:
0    5
1   -2
2    4
3    3
dtype: float64
```

One liner:

```
pd.Series([df.values[i][df.fillna(0).abs().values.argmax(axis=1)[i]] for i in range(len(df.values))])
```

Answer (score -1):

Due to my low reputation score I would like to add here to the answer of [gis20](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34131973/10794682) and the question of Andrew Hamel regarding the absolute minimum value:

```
minCol=lambda x: min(x, key=abs)
minCol=lambda x: min([abs(value) for value in x])
```

works for my data, however, it *cannot* cope with np.nan's.